# How to allow implicit conversion?

Tags: c#

Given some code like this:

```
class Json
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }

    Json MyAction()
    {
        return "{\"json\": 1}";
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can add to the `Json` class to make this compile? Something to let the compiler know that it can implicitly cast a string to a Json?

Comment: I'd add a `.ToJson()` extension method instead of overloading the `implicit` operator since this kind of implicit conversion violates some important guidelines(see Saeed's answer). In particular it can throw, isn't lossless and has strange semantics in comparisons.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I can make it not throw :) My biggest concern here is that action simply returns a different type to differentiate it from a string, even though otherwise it can act perfectly like a string. This way I know which ContentType to set without the user having to do any additional work (just set the return type of the function appropriately).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The [`implicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) operator declaration in c# allows you to specify:

```
{type to convert to} ({type to convert from} variablename)
```

Here's a simple example:

```
class Json
{
    private Json(string json)
    {
        //logic to parse string into object
    }

    public static implicit operator Json(string input)
    {
        return new Json(input);
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- First, **I wouldn't necessarily go this route**, since most strings in your application are not semantically equivalent to a JSON string. The purpose of a conversion operator is to say two types always represent semantically equivalent information (or close enough to semantically equivalent to be usefully treated as such). I'd recommend implementing a `static Json Parse(string input)` or maybe even a `static bool TryParse(string input, out Json json)` method on your Json class instead. The callsite, generally, ought to know whether it expects its own string to contain Json.
- Typically if my class offers implicit type conversion from a type, I find it best to make any parsing or ctor logic for that same type `private`. This ensures there's only one way for consumers to do a particular thing, not two ways (ctor and conversion) - hence the private ctor in the example above. There can be exceptions to this but it's been a good general rule for me.
- The implicit conversion also allows some interesting things with comparison operators. For example, now that you can implicitly convert from string to json, you can also do: `if(myJson == "blah")` and it will do the conversion and then call the `==` operator on your Json object, which by default will do a reference equality comparison.

Comment: The `implicit` link from the answer is old. Please have a look at: [user-defined-conversion-operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators)

Answer (score 4):

Add an [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) operator:

```
public static implicit operator Json(string s)
{
   return new Json(s);
}
```

> The implicit keyword is used to declare an implicit user-defined type conversion operator. Use it to enable implicit conversions between a user-defined type and another type, if the conversion is guaranteed not to cause a loss of data.

Answer (score 3):

You can have an implicit converter but take care you don't lose data:

> By eliminating unnecessary casts,
>   implicit conversions can improve
>   source code readability. However,
>   because implicit conversions can occur
>   without the programmer's specifying
>   them, care must be taken to prevent
>   unpleasant surprises. In general,
>   implicit conversion operators should
>   never throw exceptions and never lose
>   information so that they can be used
>   safely without the programmer's
>   awareness. If a conversion operator
>   cannot meet those criteria, it should
>   be marked explicit.

see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)